# Can kubernetes recognise/read EC2 instance tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I want to use Kubernetes pod affinity and anti-affinity rules to distribute pods equally among availability zones. I want to attach zone id/name as a instance tag to each EC2 instance (usual key/value pair). Can Kubernetes read these tags as labels and use in pod affinity rules or there is some additional step required? Any good practices?